# php associative array username first letter

Tags: php, associative-array

```
$array=array("sam"=>"andy");
$user="sam";
$pass="andy";
if(!in_array($user,$array)) //line no 5
    {
        echo "please register";

    }
else 
    {
        if($array[$user]==$pass)
            {
                echo "welcome";
            }
  }
```

*What changes should i do in line no 5 so user will be "sam" not "sam=>andy"??*

Comment: `!isset($array[$user])`

Comment: It seems that you are developing an auth system LOL. However, imagine that you have an array with key is username and value is its password, then you want to check if username is existed or not (line 5), then continue checking if password is matched or not, etc; just change line 5 to `if (!isset($array($user)))` to check if username is defined in `$array` or not. That is a very funny function. :D

Comment: @vietanhyt - this is a very funny function: `$array($user)` - LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a more appropriate way of doing this

```
<?php

$users = array(
    "sam" => "andy"
);

$username="sam";
$password="andy";
$errorMessage = 'invalid username or password received';

if (array_key_exists($username, $users) === false) {
    echo $errorMessage;
    exit;
}

$intendedPassword = $users[$username];
if ($intendedPassword !== $password) {
    echo $errorMessage;
    exit;
}

echo 'Hello ' . $username . ' and welcome to my beautiful web-site!';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `in_array()`, it checks if the needle exists in the *values* of the haystack (array), not in the keys. Therefore it will check if "sam" exists in an array that's for this purpose just ["andy"]. I think you wanted to check:

```
if (!in_array($user, array_keys($array)))
```

(with the caveat that I really hope this is not production code)

Comment: Or perhaps `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$user_credentials=array(
    "sam"=> password_hash("foo", PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
    "dan"=> password_hash("bar", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
);

$check_credentials = function($user, $password) use ($user_credentials)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($user, $user_credentials))
        echo "Unknown user.\n";
    else
        if(password_verify($password, $user_credentials[$user]))
            echo "Good credentials.\n";
        else
            echo "Invalid password.\n";
};

foreach(
    [
        ["sam", "baz"],
        ["sam", "foo"],
        ["peter", "parker"]
    ]
    as list($username, $password)
) $check_credentials($username, $password);
```

Output:

```
Invalid password.
Good credentials.
Unknown user.
```

Note it is recommend to store salted hashes of your user passwords, password_hash helps here.  (Of course you'd hash and store these in advance.)